# FindAll("a") in beautifulsoup python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

New to Python, can someone explain what `findAll("a")` means in below code? Can I place any other letter in place of that? like g, h, m? Does 'a' mean to find "a" in articles?

and `href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))` means to find those links which has wiki in name?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in bsObj.find("div", {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a",
href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$")):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

Can someone please suggest some good books to learn web scraping in python 3.6, where beginners can learn easily?

Comment: [Check the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findAll("a")` means search all "a" (anchor) tags

and yes you can use 'h', 'b', 'strong' and any other valid html tagname in place of 'a'

You can learn more for [BeautifulSoup here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Also `re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))` will get all links that starts with `wiki`

Comment: images = bsObj.findAll("img", {"src":re.compile("\.\.\/img\/gifts/img.*\.jpg")})
for image in images:
print(image["src"])

but in this code we are using("img") after find all?